# Create new virtualenv with selected previously installed python packages

Tags: python, virtualenv

I wish to create a new virtualenv for my project. I have just started using virtualenv. Before this, I had installed all my necessary python packages normally i.e. globally. Now I wish to create a new virtualenv with only selected packages present i.e. a new virtualenv should have a few of these installed packages present in its site-packages folder and i should be able to import them in the virtualenv. How should i go about it?

Comment: activate your virtualenv and from within it do `pip install your_packages`

Comment: is there no way to import only a specific package from global installation into a virtualenv? I will have download and install a large number of modules again otherwise

Comment: The reason of using virtualenv is to completely separate different python installations so that you can use different versions of packages for different/or same python-versions. See http://docs.python.org/2/install/#how-installation-works for how installation works. You might be able to copy content from global `site-packages` into the local.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed most of your global packages using pip, you may be able to list all current installed packages in your global installation using this:

```
pip freeze
```

You can further capture this list into a text file:

```
pip freeze  > requirements.txt
```

Edit `requirements.txt` to preserve only packages you want to carry forward to your new installation. Activate your new blank virtual and install your subset of packages:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```